# Use mitt in Vue 3 within Vuex Module Action

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3, eventemitter

I have been trying to use [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) inside my vuex module but I always get the "emitter is not defined error".

This is my main.js:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js";
import "@/assets/styles/index.scss";

import mitt from 'mitt'
const emitter = mitt()

import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(store)
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter
app.mount("#app");
```

When I try to emit an event from a vuex module action like this:

```
dispatch("settingIncommingChats", socketData.incomingChats).then(
   () => {
       emitter.emit("chats_updated");
   }
);
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: emitter is not defined
> at websocket.js:34:17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i have done is that :

mitt.js :

```js
import mitt from 'mitt';

// Create a new emitter
const emitter = mitt();

// Export that emitter
export default emitter;
```

main.js :

```js
// We recover the emitter
import emitter from './mitt';

// Vuex Store
import store from './store/store';

const app = createApp({});

app.use(store);

// We make the emitter available on window object 
// (optional but can be handy,
// if you have js files 'outside' of vue scope that needs that emitter)
window.emitter = emitter;

// We add a global $mitt property
app.config.globalProperties.$mitt = emitter;
```

so it's available inside vue with $mitt and outside vue with window.emitter if you need to

You will not have access to globally defined properties inside a vuex action though, so you will need to import it :

```js
import emitter from '@/mitt';

const actions = {};

export default actions;
```

the downside to this is that it's not the same instance, it's a new one, and it can cause issues

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to make a property global in vue 3

One of the best solution for external libs would be to create a mitt.js file in a plugins directory with the following code

```
import mitt from 'mitt'

const emitter = mitt()

export default emitter
```

Then you can import and use it in both your .js store and .vue template files

```
import emitter from "../plugins/mitt";

emitter.emit('chats_updated')
```